# New travis build request does not apply

Tags: travis-ci

After I changed my repo from PrettyTable to PTable, new build requests does not apply any more.

I tried to delete the github service and readd it, nothing changed.

My repo is here: https://github.com/kxxoling/PTable

Travis page is here: https://travis-ci.org/kxxoling/PTable

Comment: Have you synced your projects in the travis settings?

Comment: @ollo Have tried to sync it a lot of times, and even tried to deactivate travis hook. Seems travis doesn't have an api to completely clear user infomation

Comment: @ollo Fixed now. I contacted with the support team, but does not get any feedback, and tried the remove cache rest API, but get 403. I have no idea what happened, but issue fixed now.

Comment: This is a really strange problem ...